# Why do I get an error "class is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried to make an instance from modules in routing but I got always the error "class is not a constructor"

Here is my code:

```
export class Modules{

modules : object = {
    masterdata : MasterdataModule,
    shop : ShopModule
};

public constructor(){

}

public isActive(module : string) : boolean{
    return this.getModules().hasOwnProperty(module);
}

public getModules() : object{
    return this.modules;
}

public getActiveModules() : any[]{
    return ActiveModules();
}
}
```

That's my class Routing, where I tried to make an instance from Modules.

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import  {Modules} from "./modules";

export class Route{

Modules : Modules;

public constructor(){

    this.Modules = new Modules;
}

public routes() : Routes{

    let routes = [
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
        { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
        { path: 'apidemo', component: ApiDemoComponent},
        { path: 'tabledemo', component: TableDemoComponent},
        { path: 'dashboarddemo', component: DashboardDemoComponent },
        { path: 'timelinedemo', component: TimelineDemoComponent},
        { path: 'formdemo/:id', component: FormDemoComponent},
        { path: 'infopage/:subject', component: DemoPageComponent}
    ];

    console.log(this.Modules.isActive("Shop"));
    return routes;
}
}
```

both classes are in seperate files

[Here a picture from the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF32Y.png)

Comment: @jonrsharpe JavaScript allows omitting `()` on argument less constructor calls.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum oh interesting, thanks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's hard to know what problem OP has since there is code missing and OP didn't provide the stack trace or most useful debugging info.

Comment: Have you tried naming the variable other than exactly the same as the class name? (ie use `modules` or `_Modules` or anything *other* than the exact same name

Comment: What is `ActiveModules`? Is it another class?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum here is the debugging info app.routing.ts?b01c:35 Uncaught TypeError: modules_1.Modules is not a constructor
    at new Route (app.routing.ts?b01c:35)

Comment: @Jamiec i tried it already :/

Comment: @OscarPaz ActiveModules is an export function

Comment: Can you tell use the name of the files, and how are you importing `Modules` (the `import` section)? It seems that `Modules` in your routes might not be the class exported in the first file.

Comment: You're going to need to provide a [mcve] if you want an answer to this - without it this is guesswork (As you see from the answer and my comment)

Comment: Your code _is still_ not complete nor verifyable, but $10 says you're not importing `Modules` correctly, change your import from `import Modules from ...` to `import { Modules }` from ...`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum it is import { Modules } from .. already.  import  {Modules} from "./modules"; and Modules is in the same folder like app.routing

Comment: I recommend you to post the ENTIRE files and their filenames, Maybe even an image of the folder. Otherwise we can stay here forever making guesses...

Comment: @OscarPaz i did it

Comment: Apparently it should work ...  can you do this? In `Route` constructor, before calling `new Modules`: `console.log(Modules);`. Then post what this outputs to the console. Let's see what the hell that 'Modules' is.

Comment: it is undefined :O

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your "modules" variable has the same name as your class "Modules". Variables should always be lowercase to avoid such conflicts.

```html
export class Route{

modules : Modules;

public constructor(){

    this.modules = new Modules();
}
```

Comment: thank for you the answer but it isn´t right, because of (this).Modules.  it is not important if it is a lowercase or uppercase

Comment: -1 While generally good advice, this cannot cause the problem described in OP. Note that -1s don't mean I don't like or appreciate your answer :)

Comment: @leo180593 you're right. Ok sorry then this is not the solution for your problem. Maybe there is a problem with importing your class Modules.